# What could probably go wrong? Using getContentPane() as default layer JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I found out I can use `(JPanel) frame.getContentPane()` easily as default layer `JPanel`, even with borders. (Which was surprising to me at first.)

Is this a *common/uncommon/good/bad* behavior? Why?
While doing this: ***What coul probably co wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Adding Components to the Content Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane) for a brief discussion on this topic.

There is no real drawback. Your posted code already addresses the issue, mentioned in the link.